# Is the elemental weakness bonus triggered when using Summons instead of Djinn?

Tags: golden-sun-series

I'm trying to improve my chances of obtaining rare drops from random encounters using the elemental weakness as booster. I'm sure that if I use the Djinn directly I get the bonus, but, does summons count too? And summons with dual properties?

Comment: There isn't an applicable tag for *all* the series, but the mechanic is unchanged, or at least it appears to be so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure element summons doesn't, nor dual element summons. So using summons isn't recommended if you are trying to get bonuses, better to stick to offensive djinn.